# Class Attributes and Instance Attributes

Tags: python, function, oop, attributes, instance-variables

I am trying to learn the difference between the instance attributes and class attributes and attributes. I have the code below and I am trying to distinguish these factors.

```
class Student:
    firstname = ""
    lastname = ""
    ucid = ""
    department = ""
    nationality = ""
    courses = {}

    def __init__(self, fname, lname, ucid, dept, n):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname
        self.ucid = ucid
        self.department = dept
        self.nationality = n
        self.courses = {}

    def setName(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def setDepartment(self, d):
        self.department = d

    def setUcid(self, u):
        self.ucid = u

    def setNationality(self, n):
        self.nationality = n

    def addCourse(self, coursename, gpa):
        self.courses[coursename] = gpa

    def printAll(self):
        print("The name of the student is ", self.firstname, self.lastname)
        print("nationality and UCID: ", self.nationality, self.ucid)
        print("Department: ", self.department)
        print("Result: ")
        for key in self.courses.keys():
            print(key, self.courses[key])

        print("--------------------\n")

s1=Student("Beth","Bean","30303","Computer Science","International")
s1.addCourse("SCIENCE",3.75)
s1.printAll()
s2=Student("Mac","Miller","30303","Envr Science","American")
s2.addCourse("MATH",4.00)
s2.printAll()
```

From what I understood the attributes would be: `firstname,lastname,ucid,department,nationality,courses`  But I do not know what `instance attributes` and `class attributes` would be.

Comment: You've created a bunch of class attributes, the ones you define in the class scope, which you *immediately* shadow with instance attributes in `__init__`. Making those class attributes rather pointless.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am new to coding, what should I do?

Comment: Just don't define the class attributes? I't up to you. As an aside, don't write getters and setters in Python. They serve no useful purpose

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wrote getters and setters to make the code more readable but Thank you! My main question is what is  `class attributes`, `instance attributes` and `attributes ` in this case.  How can I distinguish them from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to learn the difference between the instance attributes and class attributes and attributes.

there should be two attributes, `class attribute`, `instance attribute`. or `instance attribute`&`none-instance attribute` for convenience.

#### `instance attribute`

- these are things activated only when `__init__` has been called.
- you can only access thenm after Class is initialized, which commonly seen as `self.xxx`.
- and methods in class with `self` as its first parameter(normally), these functions are instance methods, and you can only access after you initialized the Class.
- and methods in class with `@property` deco, they are instance attributes

```
common seen instance attribute 

class Name(object):
   def __init__(self):
        self.age = 100
   def func(self):
       pass
   @property
   def age(self):
       return self.age
```

#### `class attribute`

`non-instance attribute` or `static attribute`, whatever you call it

- these things stay activated along with Class.
- which means you can access them whenever you need to, like `__init__`, even in `__new__`.
- they can be called by both `Class` and `instance`.

```
common seen class attribute 

class Name(object):
   attr = 'Im class attribute'
```

there is something else you may should know, `class method`, which stay activated along with Class but the difference is `class method` can't be called by instance but only Class. example here

```
class Name(object)
   attr = 'Im class attribute'
   @classmethod
   def get_attr(cls):
       return cls.attr
```

#### Conclusion

"class attribute" can be called by both instance and Class

"instance attribute" can only called by instance.